# SharePoint list workflow - create incremental id for list item based on condition

Tags: workflow, designer

i have a SP list (Environment: 2016 on-prem) where i have a Checkbox field (Yes/No). Based on that Checkbox i want to set an incremental number to the list items. Means if the Checkbox is marked in an item of the list, it should Count a number, beginning from 1, and set it as fieldvalue to another field called "item number". if the Checkbox is unmarked, it should do Nothing on saving the list item.

So, if i create an item and mark the Checkbox, it should set the fieldvalue of "item number" to 1, when i add another item to the list and mark the Checkbox it should continue counting and set the fieldvalue of that item to 2 and so on... basically i want to add a continous counter via workflow only to items, where the Checkbox is marked.

any solutions? i'm quite new to SP designer workflows, so i would appreciate any walk-through guided solution.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. since i set the title column to hidden in my forms i guess i can just replace the above shown if condition with the checkbox one, correct? but then i think i'd need to add an "and" to check if ticketno field is empty, otherwise it would update the ticketno every time i edit the item (because i want the workflow to run only when changing items and not when creating them) is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Using SharePoint designer workflow, you can update the counter. Since this is based on another column, in the workflow you would need to add if condition to only run the update counter step if the checkbox is marked.
In the below image add if checkbox is true to the existing current title not empty.

> [image: Blockquote]

You can refer to this article on how to perform the steps.[Link](http://gihanmaduranga.blogspot.com/2012/09/create-auto-increment-number-column-in.html)